# How convert string to date format of given data in array list

Tags: java

Assume that I have a data input like this:

```
018492114,51863406,X0,1,20160218
018529816,51864472,X0,1,20150603
018543434,51864629,X0,1,20150702
018543464,51864990,N5+,1,2015063
018530309,51865142,X0,1,20150603
```

I want only to convert the 5 column's element to Date format because it was imported as a string. And I want to do a sorting operation by DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER variable (the end column).

Note that I am using arraylist object defined as Personne and I am using Comparable  interface to use Comparable  method for sorting:

this is my class personne which includes the needed object:

```
public class Personne implements Comparable {

    private String IDC_PSE_PCL;
    private String IDC_CD_NOT;
    private String CD_NOTE;
    private String IDT_ETT_PSE;
    private String DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER;

    public Personne(String IDC_PSE_PCL, String IDC_CD_NOT,
                    String DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER, String IDT_ETT_PSE, String CD_NOTE) {
        this.IDC_PSE_PCL = IDC_PSE_PCL;
        this.IDC_CD_NOT = IDC_CD_NOT;
        this.IDT_ETT_PSE = IDT_ETT_PSE;
        this.CD_NOTE = CD_NOTE;
        this.DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER = DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER;

    }

    public String getIDC_CD_NOT() {
        return this.IDC_CD_NOT;
    }

    public String getIDC_PSE_PCL() {
        return this.IDC_PSE_PCL;
    }

    public String getDA_PRM_CTR_ORDER() {
        return this.DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER;
    }

    public String getIDT_ETT_PSE() {
        return this.IDT_ETT_PSE;
    }

    public String getCD_NOTE() {
        return this.CD_NOTE;
    }

  @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Personne other = (Personne) o;
        
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); 
        Date converted = (Date) df.parse(other.getDA_PRM_CTR_ORDER());
        
                        
        int res = this.DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER.compareTo(converted);
        // Si Egalite des dates
        if (res == 0) {
            res = IDT_ETT_PSE.compareTo(other.getIDT_ETT_PSE());
        }
        return res;
    }
```

My problem is in the line:

```
    int res = this.DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER.compareTo(converted);
```

when I want to sort by DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER values but it show me this problem:

> The method compareTo(String) in the type String is not applicable for
> the arguments (Date)

How can I resolve this issue please?

Comment: you are comparing DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER, a STRING, to converted, a DATE.


Convert DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER to a date type

Comment: I bet `other.getIDT_ETT_PSE()` does not convert the `String` to a `Date`, does it? I recommend using suitable data types instead of `String`. If an attributes represents a date, use `java.time.LocalDate`, you can directly compare it since it implements `Comparable`.

Comment: @BenoitF yes I want to compare DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER . So I need to convert it to yyyymmdd date type. how I can do it ?

Comment: SA2018: the same as you do it one line earlier.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first two in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: If `DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER` always contains a date, store it as a `LocalDate` in your object rather than a string. Then comparison is trivial and doesn’t require parsing each time (which could matter if you are sorting great amounts of data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix could be to parse `this.DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER` to `Date` too. So the line you highlighted would look like:

```
int res = df.parse(this.DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER).compareTo(converted);
```

Comment: @SA2018 yes, nothing prevents to file to contain "Hello everyone" in place of "20160218", so a parsing error may occur when trying to parse the date. Choose what you want to do if such an error occurs, and make it so with try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

you should use Date.compareTo(Date) instead of String.compareTo(Date).

suggestion:

```
Long currentDate = Long.parseLong(this.DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER); 
return currentDate.compareTo(Long.parseLong(other.getDA_PRM_CTR_ORDER()));
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you compare the timestamp of two dates to compare.

```
        Date self = (Date) df.parse(this.getDA_PRM_CTR_ORDER());
        String ConvertedTs = String.valueOf(converted.getTime());
        String selfTs = String.valueOf(self.getTime());
        int res = selfTs.compareTo(ConvertedTs);
```